# Adding Classes to the FormatAreaStyles.css - Tridion 2009

Tags: 2009, format-area-styles

I am trying to edit the FormatAreaStyles.css file in Tridion 2009 to add custom classes to the dropdown in the Rich text editor.

In 2011 I know the file is here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Configuration

It seems to be in this location for 2009:

C:\Program Files\Tridion\web\Configuration

I've updated it with my classes and made sure they contain some styles. I have also cleared my browser cache but my classes to not show in the dropdown.

Can anyone give some guidance on this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the styles you're adding in the FormatAreaStyles.css file?

Comment: Have a look at section 7.3.2 ("Styles configuration") of the SDL Tridion 2009 SP1 Content Management Implementation Manual. As Mike pointed out, you may be defining styles that will not be visible...

Comment: As an example, if you define `div.callout` the `callout` class won't be available unless you're within a `div`.

Answer (score 10):

You also need to configure which styles are available for the rich text field in your Schema.

You can do this by:

1. Open the Schema
2. Select the rich text field you want to control the styles on (e.g. 'body')
3. Click on the 'Edit Formatting Features' button
4. In the pop-up, select the 'Allowed Styles' tab
5. You should now be able to choose the styles that can be used for that field

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1. Oh yeah, we need to add them *and* then use them in the rich text format areas we want. Control over these styles is a good reason to use (or not use) embedded schemas. :-)

Answer (score 8):

I always end up having to do an IISRESET to get edits picked up.

Comment: COM+ restart and clearing browser cache does the trick as well

Answer (score 6):

Search for FormatAreaStyles.css on the server - I seem to recall there are two copies of this file in 2009, and the docs pointed to the wrong one.

Answer (score 4):

Recently I had a similar problem, didn't really find the reason why certain items wouldn't show in the list of styles available but I found a solution...

This worked for me... (I had to edit the original css because I was not allowed to post it here due to exceeding max limit of characters.)

```
@charset "utf-8";


/* Framework -------------------------------------------- */

/*
body { position: relative; text-align: center; }
.stage { width: 100%; min-width: 980px; border-top: 3px solid #666666; background: url(/imgv4/common/stageborder-bottom.gif) repeat-x left bottom; }
.bodyarea { position: relative; width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 60px; text-align: left; z-index: 900; }
.bodyarea:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; width: 0; height: 0; line-height: 0; visibility: hidden; }
* html .bodyarea { display: inline-block; }
*/


/*  width: 980px;  margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 60px; text-align: left; z-index: 900; display: inline-block; content: "."; display: block; clear: both; width: 0; height: 0; line-height: 0; visibility: hidden;*/
body {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/* Contents Area */
.contentsarea { float: right; width: 781px; }

    .contentsarea .submenu { float: right; }

    /* MainContents Area */
    .maincontents { float: left; width: 582px; }


/* for modern browser exclude ie 7, 8 */
html:not(:target) body.subsidiary div#permanentmenu ul.parentcom li div.cssbtn { -moz-border-radius: 7px; -webkit-border-radius: 7px; position: relative; top: 2px; border: 1px solid #999999; }
html:not(:target) body.subsidiary div#permanentmenu ul.parentcom li div.cssbtn div.innerblock { -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; position: relative; top: -2px; border: 1px solid #111111; margin: 0 -1px -2px -1px; padding: 0; }
html:not(:target) body.subsidiary div#permanentmenu ul.parentcom li div.cssbtn div.innerblock a { -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; position: relative; top: 1px;display: block; padding: 2px 6px 3px 6px; margin-bottom: 1px; background: #222222 url(/imgv4/common/parentcomlink-bg.gif) left top repeat-x; }
html:not(:target) body.subsidiary div#permanentmenu ul.parentcom li div.cssbtn div.innerblock a img { border: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 3px; }

/* for ie 6 */
* html body.subsidiary div#permanentmenu ul.parentcom li div.cssbtn { position: relative; border: 1px solid #999999; }
* html body.subsidiary div#permanentmenu ul.parentcom li div.cssbtn div.innerblock { border: 1px solid #111111; margin: -2px -1px 0px -1px; padding: 0; }
* html body.subsidiary div#permanentmenu ul.parentcom li div.cssbtn div.innerblock a { position: relative; top: 1px; display: block; padding: 3px 6px 2px 6px; margin-bottom: 1px; background: #222222 url(/imgv4/common/parentcomlink-bg.gif) left top repeat-x; word-break: keep-all; }
* html body.subsidiary div#permanentmenu ul.parentcom li div.cssbtn div.innerblock a img { border: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 3px; }

body.subsidiary div#permanentmenu ul.parentcom li div.cssbtn div.innerblock { padding: 0; }



/* GIG4 styles --------------------------------------------------------------------- */
div.grid3span { width: 582px; }/* <-- with clearfix class */
div.grid4span { width: 781px; }/* <-- with clearfix class */
div.grid5span { width: 980px; }/* <-- with clearfix class */
div.col1span { width: 184px; float: left; margin-right: 15px; }
div.col2span { width: 383px; float: left; margin-right: 15px; }
div.col3span { width: 582px; float: left; margin-right: 15px; }
div.col4span { width: 781px; float: left; margin-right: 15px; }

fieldset { border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: #cccccc; margin: 0px; margin: 1em 0px 0px 0px; padding: 10px; }
fieldset { padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px; border: solid 1px #b5b5b5; }
textarea { padding: 4px; }

ol.number-type-alp-u { list-style-type: upper-alpha; }
ol.number-type-alp-l { list-style-type: lower-alpha; }
ol.number-type-roman-u { list-style-type: upper-roman; }
ol.number-type-roman-l { list-style-type: lower-roman; }

ul.langchanger { list-style: none; padding: 0; font-size: 93%; margin-bottom: 1.2em; }
ul.langchanger li { list-style: none; float: left; margin: 0 4px 0 0; padding: 0; line-height: 1.2; word-break: keep-all; }
ul.langchanger li a { display: block; padding: 2px 4px; background: #e3e3e3 url(/imgv4/common/langchanger-bg.gif) left bottom repeat-x; border: solid 1px #d2d2d2; }
ul.langchanger li a:link,
ul.langchanger li a:visited,
ul.langchanger li a:active { text-decoration: none; }
ul.langchanger li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

ul.alsoindex { list-style: none; padding: 0px; } /* with clearfix class */
ul.alsoindex li { list-style: none; float: left; margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 1.2; word-break: keep-all;  }
ul.alsoindex li a { display: block; padding: 4px 8px; background: #f2f2f2; border: solid 1px #e5e5e5; }
ul.alsoindex li a:link,
ul.alsoindex li a:visited,
ul.alsoindex li a:active { text-decoration: none; }
ul.alsoindex li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
ul.alsoindex strong.current { display: block; padding: 4px 8px; background: #ffffff; color: #000000; font-weight: normal; border: solid 1px #e5e5e5; }

div.wordindex { margin-bottom: 2em; }
div.wordindex div.heading { float: left; background: #e5e5e5 url(/imgv4/common/wordindex-header-bg.gif) left bottom repeat-x; }
div.wordindex h2,
div.wordindex h3,
div.wordindex h4 { margin: 0px; padding: 0px 8px; background: url(/imgv4/common/wordindex-separator.gif) right top repeat-y; font-size: 108%; line-height: 2em; font-weight: bold; word-break: keep-all; }
div.wordindex ul { list-style: none; display: block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; } /* with clearfix class */
div.wordindex li { list-style: none; display: block; float: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: #f7f7f7 url(/imgv4/common/wordindex-bg.gif) left bottom repeat-x; line-height: 2em; word-break: keep-all; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px 1px; border-color: #ffffff #b5b5b5 #ffffff #ffffff; }
div.wordindex li:first-child a { border-left: none; } /* IE lte 8 uses first-child selector width jquery */
div.wordindex li a { padding: 0px 8px; }
div.wordindex li a:link,
div.wordindex li a:visited,
div.wordindex li a:active { text-decoration: none; }
div.wordindex li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

div.pagenate {}
div.pagenate h2,
div.pagenate h3 { margin-bottom: 4px; text-align: center; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock { margin-bottom: 2em; text-align: center; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock p { display: inline; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock p.previous a { margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock p.previous img { border: none; padding-right: 5px; vertical-align: middle; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock p.next a { margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock p.next img { border: none; padding-left: 5px; text-decoration: underline; vertical-align: middle; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock a:link,
div.pagenate div.innerblock a:visited,
div.pagenate div.innerblock a:active { text-decoration: none; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
*:first-child+html div.pagenate div.innerblock a { display: inline-block; }
*:first-child+html div.pagenate div.innerblock strong { display: inline-block; }
* html div.pagenate div.innerblock a { display: inline-block; }
* html div.pagenate div.innerblock strong { display: inline-block; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock ul { list-style: none; display: inline; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock li { list-style: none; display: inline; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock li a { padding: 5px 6px; background: url(/imgv4/common/pagenate-num-bg.gif) left bottom repeat-x; border: solid 1px #b8b8b8; }
div.pagenate div.innerblock li strong.current { padding: 5px 6px; background: #ffffff none; color: #000000; border: solid 1px #e5e5e5; }
*:first-child+html div.pagenate div.innerblock li { line-height: 1.2em; }
* html div.pagenate div.innerblock li { line-height: 1.2em; }

div.moreinfo { clear: both; border-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 4px 0px 6px; }
div.moreinfo p { display: block; overflow: visible; border-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: right; font-size: 93%; }
div.moreinfo p.textleft { text-align: left; }
div.moreinfo p.textcenter { text-align: center; }
div.moreinfo p.textright { text-align: right; }
div.moreinfo p img { margin-left: 5px; border: none; }
div.moreinfo a:link,
div.moreinfo a:visited,
div.moreinfo a:active { text-decoration: none; }
div.moreinfo a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

div.scrolltop { clear: both; border-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 4px 0px 6px; }
div.scrolltop p { display: block; overflow: visible; border-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: right; font-size: 93%; }
div.scrolltop p img { margin-left: 5px; border: none; }
div.scrolltop a:link,
div.scrolltop a:visited,
div.scrolltop a:active { text-decoration: none; }
div.scrolltop a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

div.locationback { clear: both; border-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 4px 0px 6px; }
div.locationback p { display: block; overflow: visible; border-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: right; font-size: 93%; }
div.locationback img { margin-left: 5px; border: none; }    
div.locationback a:link,
div.locationback a:visited,
div.locationback a:active { text-decoration: none; }
div.locationback a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }


div.lastcol { margin-right: 0px; }

@media print { div.lastcol { margin-right: -1px; } }


/* 3-2 substitute */


.textindent { text-indent: 1em; }
.textindent1 { text-indent: 1em; }
.textindent2 { text-indent: 2em; }
.textindent3 { text-indent: 3em; }

.textleft { text-align: left; }
.textright { text-align: right; }
.textcenter { text-align: center; }

.alignleft { float: left; }
.alignright { float: right; }

.clearleft { clear: left; }
.clearright { clear: right; }
.clearall { clear: both; }

.vtop { vertical-align: text-top; }
.vmiddle { vertical-align: middle; }
.vbottom { vertical-align: text-bottom; }

a img.bordernone { border-style: none; }
img.border010 { border: solid 1px #666666; }

.notice { color: #bb0000; }
em.notice { font-style: italic; }

a.deconone { text-decoration: none; }
a.deconone:hover { text-decoration: underline; }


h1 { line-height: 1.5; }
h2 { line-height: 1.5; }
h3 { line-height: 1.5; }
h4 { line-height: 1.5; }
h5 { line-height: 1.5; letter-spacing: -0.05em; }
h6 { line-height: 1.5; letter-spacing: -0.1em; }
h2.bg010 { padding: 6px 10px; background: #f2f2f2 url(/imgv4/common/heading-bg010-bg.gif) left top repeat-x; border: solid 1px #d2d2d2; }
h3.bg010 { padding: 4px 10px; background: #f2f2f2 url(/imgv4/common/heading-bg010-bg.gif) left top repeat-x; border: solid 1px #d2d2d2; }
h4.bg010 { padding: 3px 10px; background: #f2f2f2 url(/imgv4/common/heading-bg010-bg.gif) left top repeat-x; border: solid 1px #d2d2d2; }
h5.bg010 { padding: 3px 10px; background: #f2f2f2 url(/imgv4/common/heading-bg010-bg.gif) left top repeat-x; border: solid 1px #d2d2d2; }
h6.bg010 { padding: 3px 10px; background: #f2f2f2 url(/imgv4/common/heading-bg010-bg.gif) left top repeat-x; border: solid 1px #d2d2d2; }
*:first-child+html h2.bg010 { background-position: 0px 1px; }
*:first-child+html h3.bg010 { background-position: 0px 1px; }
*:first-child+html h4.bg010 { background-position: 0px 1px; }
*:first-child+html h5.bg010 { background-position: 0px 1px; }
*:first-child+html h6.bg010 { background-position: 0px 1px; }
* html h2.bg010 { background-position: 0px 1px; }
* html h3.bg010 { background-position: 0px 1px; }
* html h4.bg010 { background-position: 0px 1px; }
* html h5.bg010 { background-position: 0px 1px; }
* html h6.bg010 { background-position: 0px 1px; }
h2.accent010 { border-left: 5px solid #bb2222; padding: 2px 0 1px 4px; }
h3.accent010 { border-left: 5px solid #bb2222; padding: 2px 0 1px 4px; }
h4.accent010 { border-left: 5px solid #bb2222; padding: 2px 0 1px 4px; }
h5.accent010 { border-left: 5px solid #bb2222; padding: 2px 0 1px 4px; }
h6.accent010 { border-left: 5px solid #bb2222; padding: 2px 0 1px 4px; }


div.heading-link { position: relative; zoom: 1; }

div.heading-link h2,
div.heading-link h3,
div.heading-link h4,
div.heading-link h5,
div.heading-link h6 { padding-right: 9.5em; }

div.heading-link p.link { display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 0px; right: 12px; text-align: right; font-weight: normal; font-size: 93%; }
div.heading-link p.link a { text-decoration: none; }
div.heading-link p.link a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
div.heading-link p.link a img { margin-left: 5px; border: none; }

div.heading-link p.h2 { padding-top: 0.8em; }
div.heading-link p.h3 { padding-top: 0.4em; }
div.heading-link p.h4 { padding-top: 0.2em; }
div.heading-link p.h5 { padding-top: 0.2em; }
div.heading-link p.h6 { padding-top: 0.2em; }

* html div.heading-link p.h2 { padding-top: 1em; }
* html div.heading-link p.h3 { padding-top: 0.7em; }
* html div.heading-link p.h4 { padding-top: 0.5em; }
* html div.heading-link p.h5 { padding-top: 0.5em; }
* html div.heading-link p.h6 { padding-top: 0.5em; }


ol.compact,
ul.compact { padding-left: 1.5em; }
dl.compact dd { padding-left: 0; }
*:first-child+html ol.compact,
*:first-child+html ul.compact { padding-left: 1.9em; }
*:first-child+html dl.compact dd { padding-left: 0; }
* html ol.compact,
* html ul.compact { padding-left: 1.9em; }
* html dl.compact dd { padding-left: 0; }

hr,
hr.line010,/* <-- className of GIG3 */
hr.line020 { height: 1px; margin: 0px 0px 2em 0px; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; border-color: #d2d2d2; background: none; color: #d2d2d2; } /* <-- className of GIG3 */

ul.datelist2col { list-style: none; padding: 0px; zoom: 1; }
ul.datelist2col li { list-style: none; margin-bottom: 0; padding-left: 24px; background: url(/imgv4/common/li_dot_lv1.gif) no-repeat 6px 0.5em; zoom: 1; }
ul.datelist2col li:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; width: 0; height: 0; line-height: 0; visibility: hidden; }
* html ul.datelist2col li { display: inline-block; }
ul.datelist2col li dl { margin: 0 0 8px; padding: 0px; zoom: 1; } /* <-- with clearfix class */
ul.datelist2col li dt,
ul.datelist2col li dd { margin-bottom: 0px; }
ul.datelist2col li dt { float: left; width: 103px; padding: 0px; }
ul.datelist2col li dd { margin-left: 113px; padding: 0px; }

ul.datelist2col-wide { list-style: none; padding: 0px; zoom: 1; }
ul.datelist2col-wide li { list-style: none; margin-bottom: 0; padding-left: 24px; background: url(/imgv4/common/li_dot_lv1.gif) no-repeat 6px 0.5em; zoom: 1; }
ul.datelist2col-wide li:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; width: 0; height: 0; line-height: 0; visibility: hidden; }
* html ul.datelist2col-wide li { display: inline-block; }
ul.datelist2col-wide li dl { margin: 0 0 8px; padding: 0px; zoom: 1; } /* <-- with clearfix class */
ul.datelist2col-wide li dt,
ul.datelist2col-wide li dd { margin-bottom: 0px; }
ul.datelist2col-wide li dt { float: left; width: 150px; padding: 0px; }
ul.datelist2col-wide li dd { margin-left: 160px; padding: 0px; }

ul.datelist2col li dl.add-icon { clear: both; overflow: hidden; /* <-- fitting boxes height */ }
ul.datelist2col li dl.add-icon dt { width: 180px; float: left; }
ul.datelist2col li dl.add-icon dt span.date { display: block; float: left; display: inline; /* <-- for IE6 float box margin bug*/ width: 103px; }
ul.datelist2col li dl.add-icon dt span.type { display: block; float: right; width: 70px; }
ul.datelist2col li dl.add-icon dt span.type img { line-height: 1; vertical-align: -0.4em; }
*:first-child+html ul.datelist2col li dl.add-icon dt span.type img { vertical-align: -0.7em; }
* html ul.datelist2col li dl.add-icon dt span.type img { vertical-align: -0.7em; }
ul.datelist2col li dl.add-icon dd { margin-left: 190px; }

ul.datelist2col-wide li dl.add-icon { clear: both; overflow: hidden; /* <-- fitting boxes height */ }
ul.datelist2col-wide li dl.add-icon dt { width: 230px; float: left; }
ul.datelist2col-wide li dl.add-icon dt span.date { display: block; float: left; display: inline; /* <-- for IE6 float box margin bug*/ width: 150px; }
ul.datelist2col-wide li dl.add-icon dt span.type { display: block; float: right; width: 70px; }
ul.datelist2col-wide li dl.add-icon dt span.type img { line-height: 1; vertical-align: -0.4em; }
*:first-child+html ul.datelist2col-wide li dl.add-icon dt span.type img { vertical-align: -0.7em; }
* html ul.datelist2col-wide li dl.add-icon dt span.type img { vertical-align: -0.7em; }
ul.datelist2col-wide li dl.add-icon dd { margin-left: 240px; }

table.standard { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px;  border: solid 1px #b8b8b8; color: #000000; }
table.standard caption { caption-side: top; padding-bottom: 0.5em; }
table.standard tr {}
table.standard th { background-color: #f2f2f2; color: #000000; border: solid 1px #aaaaaa; line-height: 1.6; }
table.standard td { background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; border: solid 1px #b8b8b8; line-height: 1.6; }
table.standard thead {}
table.standard thead th { background-color: #d2d2d2; }
table.standard thead td { background-color: #d2d2d2; }
table.standard tfoot {}
table.standard tfoot th { background-color: #999999; color: #000000; }
table.standard tfoot td { background-color: #999999; color: #000000; }
table.standard tbody {}
table.standard tbody td { background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; }

div.emphasis table.standard { border: solid 1px #ffffff; }
div.emphasis table.standard th { background-color: #d2d2d2; border: solid 1px #ffffff; }
div.emphasis table.standard td { border: solid 1px #ffffff; }
div.emphasis table.standard thead th,
div.emphasis table.standard thead td,
div.emphasis table.standard tfoot th,
div.emphasis table.standard tfoot td { background: #c2c2c2; color: #000000; }
div.emphasis table.standard tbody td { background-color: #eeeeee; color: #000000; }
div.emphasis table.standard tr.odd td { background-color: #eeeeee; color: #000000; }
div.emphasis table.standard tr.even td { background-color: #dddddd; color: #000000; }

div.stripe table.standard {}
div.stripe table.standard th { background-color: #e2e2e2; }
div.stripe table.standard td { background-color: #f2f2f2; color: #000000; }
div.stripe table.standard thead th,
div.stripe table.standard thead td { background: #d2d2d2; }
div.stripe table.standard tfoot th,
div.stripe table.standard tfoot td { background: #d2d2d2; }
div.stripe table.standard tr.even {} /* with jquery '/incv4/common/libraries/include_funcs.js' */
div.stripe table.standard tr.even td { background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; }

div.stripe div.emphasis table.standard {}
div.stripe div.emphasis table.standard th { background-color: #d2d2d2; }
div.stripe div.emphasis table.standard td { background-color: #e2e2e2; color: #000000; }
div.stripe div.emphasis table.standard thead th,
div.stripe div.emphasis table.standard thead td,
div.stripe div.emphasis table.standard tfoot th,
div.stripe div.emphasis table.standard tfoot td { background: #c2c2c2; color: #000000; }
div.stripe div.emphasis table.standard tr.even {} /* with jquery '/incv4/common/libraries/include_funcs.js' */
div.stripe div.emphasis table.standard tr.even td { background: #f2f2f2; color: #000000; }

div.frm { margin-bottom: 2em; border: solid 1px #b8b8b8; }
div.frm-bg { margin-bottom: 2em; background: #f2f2f2; border: solid 1px #b8b8b8; }
div.bg { margin-bottom: 2em; background: #f2f2f2; border: solid 1px #f2f2f2; }

div.frm-grd { margin-bottom: 2em; background: #ffffff url(/imgv4/common/box-bg-demo.gif) 0px 0px repeat-x; border: solid 1px #b8b8b8; }
div.inside { border: solid 1px #ffffff; padding: 14px 14px 0px 14px; }
div.frm div.innerblock ,
div.bg div.innerblock { padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px; } 
div.frm-grd div.innerblock,
div.frm-bg div.innerblock { padding: 14px 14px 0px 14px; }

div.rounded {
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}
div.rounded div.rounded-inside {
    border: solid 1px #ffffff;
    padding: 14px 14px 0px 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for specific details on 2011 RTF table styles and running into this post:

The table Style attribute is documented here (significance):
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-76B172A6-3509-4526-B6DE-AA795830DA48

Additional significance and how to populate values in the table Style drop down is documented here:
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-5CE5D85C-19CC-457C-A4C0-C2CE9BAA0F8C