# Tridion R5 Format Area styles path

Tags: format-area-styles

I'm trying to add the CSS that we used to have in the old version of Tridion R5.2, I have seen and I already got the path and the file in SDL Tridion 2011, but if it's possible that someone could help me to find it? does it have a different file name?
I couldn't find docs about it or maybe I don't know how to find it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I looked this up in [the old forums](https://forum.tridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=4125&SearchTerms=formatareastyles,5.2) (login required).  It appears that it should be in:

```
[Tridion]/Web/Configuration/FormatAreaStyles.css
```

Things to note:

- The changed stylesheet will only be used after you have cleared the browser cache.
- You will need to [enable this in the Schema](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/327/71)

Comment: Thank you very much I finally found it a document named "Content Management Implementation Guide 5.3" You were right I needed to log in a old forum, fortunately someone  lent me one pass. Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: So, is this question about 5.2, 5.3 or 2011? Slightly confused here :)

Comment: I think @Loren wanted to find the CSS in her R5.2 system so she could reuse it in her 2011 system, she knew where to place it in the 2011 system but was looking for the location in her R5.2 system.